# Moving Wordpress between different hosts and domains

Tags: wordpress

I currently have a wordpress blog on http://domain1.com/blog

I want to move this to http://domain2.com

http://domain1.com/blog and http://domain2.com are hosted on two different hosts.

This is what I did so far:

1. Installed Wordpress (using fantastico) on http://domain2.com
2. Downloaded wp-content folder of http://domain1.com/blog using FTP and uploaded it to http://domain2.com
3. Exported sql database of http://domain1.com/blog (from phpmyadmin)
4. Replaced all occurrences of http://domain1.com/blog to http://domain2.com (using notepad++)
5. Imported this sql file to http://domain2.com (using phpmyadmin)

The problem now is...

I am unable to login to http://domain2.com/wp-admin/ using the username and password which was working fine when I installed.

Another problem is when I point my browser to http://domain2.com it displays nothing but a blank page. A GET request is sent (as seen in Firebug) but all I see if a blank HTML response.

Any idea what I did wrong? I am willing to do it over, only if someone can guide. Please?

Comment: you did change your database settings in wp-config.php? Also test by enableing WP_DEBUG in this file.

Comment: I used fantastico to install wordpress on domain2.com so it has taken care of updating the wp-config for me. I mean the wp-config.php is pointing correctly to the domain2.com's DB details. I have imported the sql (which I exported from domain1.com/blog ) to domain2.com's DB. I guess that is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### .htaccess

If you are using pretty permalinks, there will also be references to your URL structure in the `.htaccess` file at your Blog's root folder (the file is hidden, so you might need to tell your file GUI to show it).

This is what it probably looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]


# END WordPress
```

You can see `/blog` there twice, which took care of your blog URL in the subfolder. Try changing it to `/` for your new setup.

### Salts and Keys

There are some security keys and salts in the `wp-config.php`, they look like `define('AUTH_KEY', 'KJnvuwi846%84');`

These are used for password encyption and other things. If your `wp-config.php` was not copied from your old blog but regenerated at installation, there is a good chance that your password salt was changed. This will render your password invalid, which could be the reason you cannot login.

Copy all the *KEY and *SALT values from your old `wp-config.php` to fix this.

Comment: If this doesn't help, please post your `wp-config.php` and `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue before when  i do the same.

1. Go to theme manager set the default theme and check if default theme is working proper or not.
2. If yes then all is well, now set back to your theme and test is it works.
3. If work then this is the trick when you Moving Wordpress between different hosts and domains.

If no then might be your theme problem.